# How can I create two virtual interface with java?

Tags: java, android

If I input common instruct to terminal

```
# Create a TUN interface
ip tun tap add dev tun0 mode tun
ip tun tap add dev tun1 mode tun

# Set the addresses and bring up the interface
ifconfig tun0 10.0.0.1 up
ifconfig tun1 10.0.0.2 up
```

I can create two virtual interface
http://ppt.cc/vKI4n

I try to use builder with java like below (builder is the helper class used for creating a VPN interface)

```
private ParcelFileDescriptor mInterface, mInterface2;

Builder builder = new Builder();
Builder builder2 = new Builder();

builder.addAddress("10.8.0.2", 20);
builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);
builder2.addAddress("10.8.0.3", 20);

mInterface = builder.establish();
mInterface2 = builder2.establish();
```

but builder can't create two interface simultaneously.

mInterface2 will overwrite mInterface1.

How can I use java code to create two interface simultaneously?

Comment: Builder is your class or part of some API ?

Comment: Builder is VpnService class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html  but it can not create multi tun

Comment: Yes, I want to produce two tun(virtual interface), but builder can not use. If I builder2.addAddress, it will overwrite builder.addAddress.

Comment: Have any method to help create two tun?